# page not centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

i can load the page and it will be all the way to the left press refresh and it then loads centered! im using chrome!  http://www.soldbybillcox.com/index.html

also on http://www.soldbybillcox.com/listings.html I cant seem to get the page to be centered!

and to top it all off some how removing www. from the url determines if the scroll bar will appear in the iframe

Comment: No-repro. Also, too localized. Also also, every single sentence doesn't have to end in an exclamation mark.

Comment: Nice, you fixed it for FF at least. Now it's broken for Chrome. And it's broken because of the `clear: left;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome and ie loads two pages opposite of each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480380/chrome-and-ie-loads-two-pages-opposite-of-each-other)

Comment: If your question is not getting any answers, consider re-phrasing it or adding more information, Ask yourself "Could I answer this question as is stands now?" If not, do it over. Don't post the same question twice, it's likely to get closed.

Comment: umm i actually did reword it. @KyleSevenoaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole page in a DIV tag, like this:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 912px;">
    /*You page and stuff*/
</div>
```

Note that the '912' can change, just make it the exact same as your page's width.

Comment: Just FYI, `margin: 0 auto` is much clearer. ;-)

Comment: I had this styled this way but i went in and added as you suggested and it worked!Wondering why adding the style didnt work but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

wrap your whole content with a

```
<div id="container" style="margin:0 auto width:960px">
All the content here...
</div>
```